# Using ModSecurity as transparent mode

Tags: mod-security, waf

> I want to use Mod Security as transparent mode. Mod security WAF should be between server and client and client provided with only server's ip address to access the site. The client should not aware about the presence of Mod security since it provided server's ip address unlike in reverse proxy mode.
>   Is it possible to use mod security as mentioned above.?

I want to deploy mod security as transparent proxy (layer 7). As imperva has deployed WAF. See Deployment Modes in specification Tab  [Link](http://www.imperva.com/products/wsc_web-application-firewall.html) .

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. ModSecurity is a server-side technology. It doesn't sit between your server and client.

Answer (score 2):

ModSecurity is just a module for apache web server and we need to to add Modsecurity module in the apache configuration for the modsecurity to work. In order for the modsecurity to work we need to configure modsecurity as a reverse proxy we need to configure apache configuration like an example.

[image]

For the understanding of basic reverse proxy configuration i would recommend you to read 
[Improve LAMP security with Apache Proxy's directive (mod_proxy)](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-lampsec/index.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but its not my answer and I'm expecting my correct answer from you @Ali sir.Please check the link provided in question and see what I said to check.

Comment: @DanielExar you can configure apache 2.2 as a transparent proxy and configure modsecurity with it. you can read this http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/apache/users/312902